# How to add property on TextNode with unifiedjs

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

```js
import { unified } from 'unified';
import { visit } from 'unist-util-visit';
import rehypeDomParse from 'rehype-dom-parse';
import rehypeDomStrigify from 'rehype-dom-stringify';

const processor = unified()
  .use(rehypeDomParse)
  .use(() => (tree) => {
    visit(
      tree,
      (node) => {
        if (
          ['script', 'style'].includes(node.tagName) &&
          node.children.length === 1
        )
          return true;
        return false;
      },
      (node) => {
        node.children[0].lang = '';
      },
    );
  })
  .use(rehypeDomStrigify);
  // .data('settings', { fragment: false })

const file = await processor.process(`<style>body {height: 100vh}</style>`);
const tree = processor.parse(file);

console.log(tree);
```

Is there anyone knows how to correct it?

I have tried return new TextNode and add the `lang` directly like above example, but the result ast tree don't include `lang`.